# Cross link suggestion algorithm that distributes and spans all links as fast as possible without loops

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

I am implementing a topic suggestion system to a website. The aim is to add links to the left panel of each topic. For example, I opened the topic named "topic1", left of the page should show 5 additional topic links, say "topic48", "topic1453", "topic1905", "topic35", "topic63". Objectives are as follows:

1) Distribute all topics equivalently, so that topics are referenced by almost the same number of other topics. For example, every topic is referenced minimum 10, maximum 15 times.

2) Regardless of which topic I started to display, all topics should be suggested as shallow as possible. For example: let's say I have 10 topics with ids [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and we need to suggest 3 topics for each topic. The suggestion tree should be as follows:

```
                            3
          |                 |                   |
          8                 4                   6
      |   |   |         |   |   |           |   |   |
      1   7   9         2   5   10         ...  ... ...
```

As you can see, all topics should be suggested as shallow as possible.

3) There should not be such loops:

topic1 -> topic2, topic7, topic9

topic2 -> topic1, topic7, topic9

topic7 -> topic1, topic9, topic2

topic9 -> topic1, topic2, topic7

Is there such algorithm(s) to provide that functionality. Any suggestions?

Comment: Topic suggestion systems usually try to suggest *relevant* topics. How does that aspect figure in in your system?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The aim is to make the user iterate all the topics so that he/she can discover the whole website.